# Apache 2.4 With Tomcat 8 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8, apache2.4, apache2.2

Elastic beanstalk with tomcat8 comes with Apache 2.2 as its default proxy server.

How can you configure Apache 2.4 via .ebextensions and is this safe?